# Looping ggplot/ggvis over identical columns and rows in two datasets

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggvis

I am fairly new to R and therefore have to bother you with a basic question.

I have two large panel datasets (60 variables, each for 30 countries, ranging over a period from 1950-2013). The 60 variables have identical names, the data may or may not differ.

My final goal is to create 60 grids with 30 plots each: each grid refers to one of the 60 variables and contains a plot for each country. Each plot will contain 2 line graphs, one from the first data frame and one of the second (for the same variable each).

I have done this in Stata before, using global vars and a simple loop. I am stuck in trying to make this work in R.

I cast the data into wide format for now (columns: Date, Country, Indicator1,...Indicator60), but have read that ggplot2 does better with long formats(?).

My main issue is how to loop at all (for, lapply, function..). .

If not an answer, I would hugely appreciate ideas or hints at how to approach this problem, so that I would manage to ask more specific questions, if needed.

Edit: below a reproducible sample of the data, as requested

```
year <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013,2010, 2011, 2012,     
    2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012,    
    2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
country <- c(rep("Australia", times =8), rep("Canada", times = 8),  
    rep("Australia", times =8), rep("Canada", times = 8))
indicator <- c(rep("Apples", times = 16), rep("Bananas", times = 16))
versiondata <- c(rep("new", times = 4), rep("old", times = 4), rep("new",  
    times = 4), rep("old", times = 4), rep("new", times = 4), rep("old", 
    times = 4), rep("new", times = 4), rep("old", times = 4))
value <- runif(32)
mydf <- data.frame(year, country, indicator, versiondata, value)
```

I am still stuck at the exact expression of the do. I came up with this sorry bit, where I do not know how to specify the two y-variables (corresponding to old and new from the column versiondata).

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(indicator) %>%
  do({
    p <- ggplot(., aes(x=year)) + 
      geom_line(aes(y = ???)) 
    + facet_wrap(~country) + ggtitle("indicator")
    })
```

Comment: It'd help to see a reproducible sample of your data

Comment: Use a long format. Combine your data into one data frame with a `source` column specifying the data source. Then use `dplyr` to group by variable and `do` a plot on that subset of data.

Comment: @Señor O, I have edited my post to add some reproducible sample of the data. Thanks for any help and apologies, I am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly standard approach for this kind of thing would be:

```
by(mydf, mydf$indicator, function(X) ggplot(X, aes(year, value, color = versiondata)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~country))
```

Using the indicator name as a title can be take a little more finesse:

```
lapply(unique(mydf$indicator), function(X) ggplot(mydf[mydf$indicator == X,], aes(year, value, color = versiondata)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~country) + labs(title = X))
```

Should look like this for each indicator:

[image]

Comment: wow, many thanks! I didn't think it could be solved in such a concise way. Thank you very much. While experimenting with this code I encountered two more issues I couldn't solve so far. Firstly, I wanted to give the two lines ("new" and "old") differing widths, but after some trial and error and googling I could not find a way to implement this. Secondly, my actual dataset has a larger x axis, so I wanted to set the tickmark intervals. I added this bit to the code: scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1970,1980,...2015)) , but receive the error "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".

Comment: @LevanK. just use the `size` argument: `... + geom_line(aes(size = versiondata)) + ...`. For your axes, check to make sure you x-value data **is** continuous, and isn't of type `factor` or `character` or something

Comment: I had already figured out the size feature: size = versiondata in aes and the additional argument scale_size_manual(values = c(...)). It is amazing what you can do in ggplot2! Regarding the date, I used mydf$year <- as.Date(mydf$year) before making the plots, but it yields the exact same error as before.

Comment: @LevanK. `as.Date(mydf$year)` should return an error! You can't turn "2012" into a date because it'a  year, **not** a date. You need to either turn `mydf$year` into *full* dates (i.e. `2010-01-01`) or stick with integers (probably the better option if it's only the year you care about). Note that `c(1970, 1980, ...)` is not of type "Date" so it's no surprise you're getting an error there!

Comment: I should have specified that my actual data is of monthly frequency (%Y-%m-%d format). As it was by default Posixct I tried to turn it into date, as specified previously. After reading your comment I declared the vector c(1970,..) as Date, but that does not seem to be the solution either (same error)

Comment: @LevanK. got it. Sounds like the kind of thing you may want to post a new question about. In making a small sample dataset that reproduces *that* problem, you may discover what's causing it in the process (happens to me all the time! haha)